# How do apps pick large videos from file without maxing memory

Tags: react-native, video, expo, out-of-memory

We have an app (React Native Expo SDK 44) that needs to pick large video (1gb +) from the devices files.

Every library we've tried fails because the device runs out of memory

We tried uploading the 1gb video file to apps like YT & Reddit with no issues. How do these sites achieve picking the video without running out of memory?

Comment: Define **uploading**... You make it seem like you want user-selected file in memory to use in-app but then you compare to Youtube who are transferring video bytes from local to their server.... Which one are you doing? What are you trying to achieve **specifically** 
 with the large videos? There might be another way to achieve that same goal.

Comment: **(1) Upload to server...** Can you not read the file as chunks and then join the pieces on server side (not obvious if your upload to server is being handled by a PHP file). **(2) Upload to web page...** If using only in-app then maybe try a file reference (meaning you note the file's location but not load any of it into memory) in JS you would use the File API to `readasDataURL` instead of `readasArray` so find equivalent options in React.